# Select subset of elements and their children in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, rails-postgresql

I have a collection of albums and each album has songs.

I want to filter all albums where most played songs are and inside these albums have references only to the most played songs.

Something like

```
Album.includes(:songs).order("songs.played_count DESC").limit(10)
```

But this limits albums and not songs.

I want 10 most played songs and albums for that.

If I go from other side such as

```
Song.includes(:album).order("songs.played_count DESC").limit(10)
```

I got all the songs, but I want to receive albums. For this example I would have to go through songs and create a collection of albums and for each album set only the selected songs.

Is there any better way how to achieve it?

My Models

```
Artist 
  name 
  has_many :albums

Album 
  title 
  year
  has_many :songs
  belongs_to :artist 

Song 
  title 
  played_count 
  new
  belongs_to :album
```

***UPDATE***

Example of result I expect.

Top 10 songs

```
Bad Religion - The New America  | I Love My Computer 
Linkin Park - Living Things     | Caste of Glass
Linkin Park - Living Things     | Skin to Bone
Kiss - Monster                  | Freak 
Within Tempt. - Q Music Session | Titanium
Sunrise Avanue - On The Way ..  | Fairytale Gone Bad
Linkin Park - Living Things     | Roads Untravelled
Within Tempt. - Q Music Session | Radioactive
```

Expected result

```
Album <Bad Religion - The New America>  
   Song <I Love My Computer>

Album <Linkin Park - Living Things>
  Song <Castle of Glass>
  Song <Skin to Bone>
  Song <Roads Untravelled>

Album <Kiss - Monster>
  Song <Freak>

Album <Within Tempt. - Q Music Session>
  Song <Titanium>
  Song <Radioactive>

Album <Sunrise Avanue - On The Way ..>
  Song <Fairytable Gone Bad>
```

Simple query would look like

```
SELECT albums.*, songs.* FROM albums 
LEFT JOIN songs 
   ON songs.album_id = albums.id 
ORDER BY songs.most_played 
LIMIT 10
```

And this query returns 10 objects and I would need turn them into Albums including their Songs based on this query

I hope I cleared the question.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Rails Doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

> If you eager load an association with a specified :limit option, it will be ignored, returning all the associated objects.

Instead, try this:

```
Album 
  title 
  year
  has_many :songs
  has_many :most_played_songs, -> { order('played_count DESC').limit(10) }, :class_name => 'Song'
  belongs_to :artist
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this gives me access to ten most played songs for each album, is it right?

Comment: Well, It's not what I meant. I want a subset of Albums including a subset of Songs (from top ten) that are most played. For example If I have 10 top played songs and these songs are from 5 albums, I want filter only those 5 albums and those albums include just only the songs from top 10.